# AWS Lambda and X-Ray: (Python) How To Install

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-xray

TL;DR How do I install AWS X-Ray sdk, because the pip install doesn't seem to get the full package

Hello Folks,

I'm working on trying out AWS X-Ray for my Python lambda.  I know the library is large, but I wanted to get a POC before putting it into a layer.  The issue is that when I install it, it doesn't seem to get installed.

When I run `pip install -r requirements.txt` I see that it installs two packages, `aws_xray_sdk` and `aws_xray_sdk-2.9.0.dist-info`.  When I look into these packages I see that they are 740 kilobytes altogether (makes me think this is a stub of some sort)

When I upload my lambda and test it, I get the following error even though the directories are in my venv:

`[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'users/main': No module named 'aws_xray_sdk' Traceback (most recent call last):`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you installing it into your lambda?

Comment: @gshpychka I zip my folder then upload to S3.  I update the function with an `aws` client call.

Comment: "makes me think this is a stub of some sort" - no, this is not try at all, you can download the latest release of the package from [github](https://github.com/aws/aws-xray-sdk-python/releases/tag/2.9.0), it is `668 KB` on my drive. It is not huge, I don't know from where did you get this information.

Comment: How are you making sure to include the installed packages in the zip file? Are you sure you're including your dependencies in it and not just installing it system-wide?

Comment: @gshpychka I was not putting my deps in the root of the zip file.  They were stuck in my `venv`.  I had been getting away with it for so long because I only was using `boto3` as a dep, and it already exists in the Lambda environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was not putting my dependencies in the root of my .zip file as the docs clearly show ='(

[4. Create a deployment package with the installed libraries at the root.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html)

Answer (score 1):

To install the X-Ray SDK for Python, you simply do `pip install aws-xray-sdk` and that should work. This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-tracing.html).

If this is not working, there is something else that's wrong with your setup.